# Can't get new iOS 7 camera to scale inside UIPopoverController

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios7

My iOS 6 code to show the camera in a UIPopoverController works fine but iOS won't scale the camera view.  Please see images below. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

## Edit

```
public class NoRotationUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController
{
    public override bool ShouldAutorotate ()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//place imagePicker into a container so that we can control the size of the popover
container = new UIViewController();
container.ContentSizeForViewInPopover = new SizeF(parentViewController.View.Frame.Width, parentViewController.View.Frame.Height);
container.View.AddSubview(_imagePicker.View);

_popOver = new UIPopoverController (container); 

//If no camera is available, return false and do nothing.
if (IsCameraHardwareAvailable())
{
    _imagePicker.Delegate = new PopUpGalleryPickerDelegate (_popOver, _imageSelected);
    _imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
    _imagePicker.AllowsEditing = false;             
    _imagePicker.MediaTypes = new string[] {"public.image"};

    RectangleF popRectangle = new RectangleF (new PointF(parentViewController.View.Frame.Width/2, parentViewController.View.Frame.Height/2), new SizeF (1, 1));

    _popOver.PresentFromRect(popRectangle, parentViewController.View, 0, true); 
    _imagePicker.View.Frame = container.View.Frame;  //change to frame must come after popover is presented.
}
else
{
    cameraAvailable = false;
}
```

[image: iOS 6 View]
[image: iOS 7 View]

Comment: could you try `_imagePicker.view.bounds = container.view.bounds;` instead of setting frame?

Comment: No change.  Still the same issue.

Comment: Another thing to make sure you are implementing `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations` and `ShouldAutorotate` on each controller in the popover. This would include the `UIImagePickerController`, so you might have to subclass some of them.

Comment: I updated my code above.  We override ShouldAutorotat because we only support Landscape.

Comment: Oh this is monotouch? Might be a mono issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up with was to make the camera full screen instead of using a popover controller.